# Failed to compile input schema(s)! Error messages should have been provided

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I want to consume a SOAP web service using Spring Boot. For this purpose, I have been given one WSDL URL by the company. **I have just changed the company name with test because I cannot expose the company name but URL is valid.** When I am clicking this URL then WSDL file is generated on the browser.

```
https://uat.test.co.in/cordys/WSDLGateway.wcp?service=http://schemas.cordys.com/default/getIDV&organization=o=B2C,cn=cordys,cn=defaultInst106,o=mydomain.com
```

To convert WSDL to Java classes I am using `maven-jaxb2-plugin` and as we know this plugin automatically converts the WSDL into Java Binding classes if URL is live or valid.

This is my plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
        <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
        <generatePackage>com.groupbima.consume</generatePackage>
        <schemas>
            <schema>
                <url>https://uat.bhartiaxaonline.co.in/cordys/WSDLGateway.wcp?service=http://schemas.cordys.com/default/getIDV&amp;organization=o=B2C,cn=cordys,cn=defaultInst106,o=mydomain.com</url>
            </schema>
        </schemas>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If URL is not live or valid then it rise errors like this

```
Failed to compile input schema(s)!
Error messages should have been provided.
(org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate:default:generate-sources)
```

> My URL is live and valid but still it is raising same error.

I have another WSDL URL which is created by me

```
http://localhost:8080/ws/employees.wsdl
```

When I am using the same plugin then automatically `maven-jaxb2-plugin` converts the WSDL into Java Binding classes.

> But when I am using this `https://uat.test.co.in/cordys/WSDLGateway.wcp?service=http://schemas.cordys.com/default/getIDV&organization=o=B2C,cn=cordys,cn=defaultInst106,o=mydomain.com` URL then it is not generating any classes and I am facing 
>   this issue.

```
Failed to compile input schema(s)!
Error messages should have been provided.
(org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate:default:generate-sources)
```

> How to resolve this issue?

Comment: your localhost URL is `http` whereas your target url is `https`. Could you cross check whether there is any SSL certificate issue with the URL `https://uat.test.co.in....`. Please provide maven error logs if that's not sensitive.

Comment: **This is maven error log**

    Failed to compile input schema(s)Error messages should have been provided. (org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate:default:generate-sources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to compile input schema(s)! Error messages should have been provided.
 at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.generateCode(XJC22Mojo.java:70)
 at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:41)
 at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:28)
 at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:505`

Comment: You should provide the complete error log, not just the exception.

Comment: How can I provide complete log even comment supports only 600 characters?

Comment: Post your log on some other site like Pastebin, gist, etc. and give the link in a comment here, or edit your original post.